# Newbie Programmer needs Motivation

Tags: php

I'm starting to teach myself computer programming. I am interested in developing a website using PHP but I don't know what kind of concept I should develop. Please advise me on any good ideas for how I can improve my programming skills.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I would say this is both programming related and a real question, so it shouldn't be closed.. though it may be a duplicate cause I think I've seen other similar quesitons

Comment: @High I believe he is saying he is interested in programming, but doesn't know what to actually program... idk his title and body of the question don't completely match up.

Answer (score 4):

When I started learning PHP, I started by writing a content management system.  Turns out that it was the worst content management system in human history, but I sure learned a lot.  Another friend of mine learned PHP through programming a web based game.

Point is, try to find something interesting that will keep your attention for a long development process!  Then, resign yourself to a very long learning curve.

Comment: It was the second worst.  Trust me.

Comment: No no, you didn't see mine! It had a PHP file that worked as a database and it comments and other user info went into the "database" All someone had to type was `"; I is executing codez on your server`

Comment: You know, we may have to have a bad CMS-off to settle this once and for all.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Write an application for something you are passionate about.

Examples are: book/cd/dvd collection manager

Comment: you have a strange definition of "passionate"

Answer (score 2):

An old mentor of mine, when asked the same question, replied "scratch an itch".

Is there a problem that you need a solution to, that no decent solution currently exists for?

Try to avoid putting the cart before the horse; choose your problem to solve, then find the best platform to implement it on.  In any case, the skills you will acquire by cutting code will be applicable regardless of the languages and libraries you choose to use.  Choice of programming language and platform is less important than actually cutting code and building something interesting and useful.

Answer (score 1):

One of the secrets to being a successful programmer is finding the motivation. If you don't work as a programmer its often difficult to find the motivation to continue with your studies.

Here is my solution. Head over to [www.elance.com](http://www.elance.com). Find a super simple project related to developing websites with PHP. Make a low bid an explain that you are willing to work for cheap in exchange for feedback. You will now have a project, a paycheck, and motivation to continue your studies. Bust you butt getting this project completed (use stackoverflow.com if you get stuck).

The best part is you will be developing you resume which will help you land a "real job" if that is your goal.

The best of luck to you

Comment: could you really, ethically charge someone money for your first ever programming project?

Comment: @nickf-As long as you're up front about it, I'd say yes.  It's the unrevealed information that would make it unethical.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out something you have a use for, and program than.  Here is an idea for a program I could use and may write myself.  I offer this only as an example, but you're welcome to write it for me if you like!

1. Site allows you to enter a list of categories and search terms.
2. Whenever you visit the page, the system searches a specified craigslist website for each of the search terms you listed within the specified category.
3. The system then consolidates the results (so items matching more than one search show up only once) and formats them for display.
4. The display includes a link back to the original craigslist website.

Example: I specify that I want to search the furniture section of the SF Bay Area craigslist site for "sofa", "console table", and "Ethan Allen".  Whenever I visit my search page, I see a current listing of all ads matching my search criteria.

Extra Credit: Extend the idea to other sites (ebay, for instance), still presenting a consolidated, current listing.

Comment: You have to give me a link to this site when your done :)